# Need help using jQuery (or a plugin) to create a constantly moving picture (in one direction that repeats)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a very long image.  I would like separate the image into maybe 10 (so that each part is a separate link) but have the whole thing slide in one direction, smoothly (and repeat).  I would also like the ability to start at any point in the image randomly.  I can't seem to find a good jQuery plugin to get started on this.  Do you have any ideas?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change div background image location dynamically using JavaScript with setInterval function

Comment: good idea.  So i set an interval for every x seconds to dynamically change the css "left" part, then check when an image goes too far and move it back to the other side?

Comment: No, you will have repeating background, so you will not need to check if image is "finished"

Comment: Could you explain how this works if the image is split into 10 different images each with a different link/mouseover event?  I don't get how that would work.

Comment: thank you...http://i0.kym-cdn.com/profiles/icons/big/000/050/000/mind%20blown.gif

Comment: Wait, one more thing, using the map makes it so I can't make it a background image, which means it can't repeat.  How do I get horizontal repetition with an image using a map?